# Add or do not add WWW hostnames to SAN certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, redirect

My setup is as follows:

- 100+ websites
- Each website has two host headers `any.com` and `www.any.com`
- Requests for `www.any.com` are redirected to `any.com` without changing protocol
- ***Some*** of these websites need SSL
- Requests for `http://sslonly.com` are redirected to `https://sslonly.com`
- I have a multiple domain (a.k.a. UCC/SAN) SSL certificate that allows up to 50 subject alternative names

My questions:

1. What is the best way to set up subject alternative names on the SSL certificate? Do I need to add **both** `sslonly.com` and `www.sslonly.com` or just `sslonly.com`?
2. What is the best way to set up the redirects?

I am using IIS 8.5

Comment: Most **non**-SAN vendors automatically add the www variant, but I haven't encountered one that does it for SAN certs. I'd always include both variants, as you'll find plenty of people type in both ways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should add all names that are used for redirects. That is, if you connect to `https://example.com` and this site redirects to `https://www.example.com` and it is the same web site, then your certificate must include both, `example.com` and `www.example.com` in the Subject Alternative Names extension. If any redirect host part is not listed in the certificate, redirect will fail and stop at this point with certificate error in browser.

Comment: actually it would be the other way round (www to no-www). Does this matter.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. What matters: each redirect host part must be included in SAN extension of the certificate. The order is irrelevant.

Comment: It's possible to also use a wildcard like *.domain.com but that can open up security issues. It's better to include domain.com and www.domain.com if that's all you're using.